# Unable to create a version in Cloud AI Platform using custom containers for prediction

Tags: docker, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

Because of certain VPC restrictions I am forced to use custom containers for predictions for a model trained on Tensorflow. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-container-requirements) requirements I have created a HTTP server using Tensorflow Serving. The Dockerfile used to `build` the image is as follows:

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:2.3.0-gpu

# copy the model file
ENV MODEL_NAME=my_model
COPY my_model /models/my_model
```

Where `my_model` contains the `saved_model` inside a folder named `1/`.

I have then pushed the container image to Artifact Registry and then created a `Model`. To create a `Version` I have selected `Customer Container` on the Cloud Console UI and and added the path to the `Container Image`. I have then mentioned the **Prediction route** and the **Health route** to be `/v1/models/my_model:predict` and have changed the **Port** to `8501`. I have also selected the machine type to be a single compute node of type n1-standard-16 and 1 P100 GPU and kept scaling `Auto scaling`.

After clicking on **Save** I can see the Tensorflow Server starting and while viewing the logs we can see the following messages:

```
Successfully loaded servable version {name: my_model version: 1}

Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500

Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501

NET_LOG: Entering the event loop
```

However after about 20-25 minutes the `version` creation just stops throwing out the following error:

```
Error: model server never became ready. Please validate that your model file or container configuration are valid.
```

I am unable to figure why this is happening. I am able to run the same docker image on my local machine and I am able to successfully get predictions by hitting the endpoint that is created: http://localhost:8501/v1/models/my_model:predict

Any help is this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this myself after working with the Google Cloud Support Team to figure out the error.

Turns out the port I was creating a `Version` on was conflicting with the Kubernetes deployment on Cloud AI Platform's side. So I changed the `Dockerfile` to the following and was able to successfully run Online Predictions on both Classic AI Platform and Unified AI Platform:

```
FROM tensorflow/serving:2.3.0-gpu

# Set where models should be stored in the container
ENV MODEL_BASE_PATH=/models
RUN mkdir -p ${MODEL_BASE_PATH}

# copy the model file
ENV MODEL_NAME=my_model
COPY my_model /models/my_model

EXPOSE 5000

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["tensorflow_model_server", "--rest_api_port=8080", "--port=5000", "--model_name=my_model", "--model_base_path=/models/my_model"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different health path?
I believe `/v1/models/my_model:predict` uses `HTTP POST`, but health checks are usually using `HTTP GET`

You might need a `GET` endpoint for your health check path.

Edit: From the docs https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest you might be able to test just using `/v1/models/my_model` as your health endpoint